# ¿Cómo definir una función en python que reciba parametros variables?

Tags: python, array, bucle-for, concat

Tengo la siguiente función en python:

```py
def graficar(mes,propietario):
    filtro_mes_cliente = (dfout['MES'] == mes) & (dfout['Propietario'] == propietario) 
    dfout_dia = dfout[filtro_mes_cliente].groupby(['DIA'])[['Palletsout']].sum()  
    sns.barplot(x = dfout_dia.index, y = dfout_dia['Palletsout'])
    sns.set_style("whitegrid")
   
   Def Graficar []
      if len ([]) == 0
       print(dfin)
      else
         dfin = dfin ['Propietario'] == cliente
```

Necesito que esta funcion reciba por ejemplo uno o varios o todos los propietarios. Osea que sea variable. Tengo entendido que puedo usar un array pero la verdad no sé como he intentado lo siguiente:

Definí la función si el arreglo es '0' debe imprimir todo el df. Sino me debe imprimir el cliente solicitado, sé que debo usar concatenar para sumar los df resultantes. Pero no sé como hacerlo. Y tengo que usar un for para recorrer los propietarios en caso de que los pidan.

Me podrían ayudar?

Comment: Está explicado en el tutorial https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists. En esa misma página está todo lo que necesitas saber sobre uso de funciones.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de nada, te recomendaría que la próxima vez dedicaras 10 minutos extra a escribir de forma coherente y detallada la pregunta, incluyendo buen código de ejemplo para que el resto de personas podamos entender de manera fácil lo que quieres saber.

Dicho esto, python tiene varios mecanismos para gestionar los argumentos variables en las funciones:

## 1. Uso de **kwargs

Por lo general, esta es la versión que prefiero utilizar y la que suelo ver en otros códigos. Básicamente, la definición de la función vendría a ser

```
def imprime_campos(nombre, edad, **kwargs):
    print(nombre, edad) # imprime "pepe 30"
    for k in kwargs:
        print(k, kwargs.get(k)) # imprime el argumento y su valor
```

En este bloque, kwargs es un diccionario donde cada una de las claves son los argumentos VARIABLES que le pases a la función. De esta forma, podrás definir distintos comportamientos según la llamada a la función sea `imprime_campos(nombre='pepe', edad=30)` o `imprime_campos(nombre='pepe', edad=30, dni='xxx', gustos='si')`.

Esto es especialmente útil cuando tienes un conjunto de argumentos de interés conocidos de antemano, puesto que puedes modificar el comportamiento de tu código según un argumento se encuentre en `kwargs` o no.

Como nota final, recomiendo usar `kwargs.get(arg1)`, en lugar de `kwargs[arg1]`, puesto que el primero no lanzará una excepción en el caso en el que la función  no haya recibido el argumento `arg1` (la segunda opción dará `KeyError`).

## 2. Uso de *args

Muy parecido al primer caso, pero aquí los argumentos se sobreentienden con un orden concreto. Es decir, no vienen identificados de la forma `nombre_argumento=valor_argumento` (como con `**kwargs`).
El uso sería algo asi:

```
def imprime_campos(nombre, edad, *args):
    print(nombre, edad)
    for k in args:
        print(k)  # imprime todos los argumentos que estén despues de "nombre" y "edad"
```

## 3. Pasar una lista con un conjunto de argumentos

Personalmente descartaría esta opción, ya que si el número de argumentos y/o la casuística se complica (las combinaciones de parámetros que pueden estar o no presentes), el código se volverá demasiado complicado de manera innecesaria (sobre todo cuando tienes opciones mas "pythonicas").
En cualquier caso, podrías usar algo así, asumiendo que `argumentos` es una lista:

```
def imprime_campos(argumentos:list):
    if len(argumentos) == 2:
        nombre, edad = argumentos  
    elif len(argumentos) == 3:
        nombe, edad, dni = argumentos   
    ... # necesario programar todos los casos...

    # código de la función
```

En resumen, mi forma recomendada para tratar las funciones con parámetros variables es el uso del diccionario `kwargs` (mediante la nomenclatura `**kwargs` en la definición de la función).

Comment: Si la pregunta no está bien escrita o no es clara entonces te recomiendo no contestarla hasta que el autor la edite y la mejore. Te recomiendo leer [answer]